# How to index the second-to-last appended row? Numpy and Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, rows

I have been perplexed by this for quite some time. How to index the second-to-last appended row?

I have tried just about every possible indexing combination trying to index the second to last appended row, all returning either the last row or an error. These are some of the methods I've tried(with switching the numbers inside these methods):[-1][0], arr[-1, 0], arr[-2,1], arr[-2,:] etc. The loop I use is down below.

```
r= is an array formatted like so [[300 240 22 22]] 

arr=[] #shape is (0,)
for (x, y, w, h) in r:
    wm=int(x+ (w/2.))
    hm=int(y+ (h/2.))
    arr.append([numpy.float32(wm), numpy.float32(hm)])
return numpy.array(arr)
```

This produces 
Indexing the array (in the idle) fetches(I copied the last two blocks of the array):

```
[[293.51373 323.4329 ]
  [247.77493 316.02783]]

[[292.9887  322.23425]
 [247.24142 314.2921 ]]

the shape of the returned array is (2,2) and is dtype:float32
```

On my program, it shows up as (the same array)
--wm element------------------hm element
`[[293.51373 323.4329 ][247.77493 316.02783]]` I consider this the second to last row
`[[292.9887  322.23425][247.24142 314.2921 ]]` and I thought this was the last row

Which brought up some confusion for me, because they are showing up a little differently(the idle one shows that the array is 2 lines and the other one shows me that its one straight line)

These are some examples of indexing methods(along with the array)(these are the two last consecutive lines from the array):

```
arr [[255.44836 280.92575] # i want to index this line
 [298.6107  285.75986]]
arr[-1] [298.6107  285.75986]
arr[-2] [255.44836 280.92575]
arr[-2][0] 255.44836
arr[:,0] [255.44836 298.6107 ]
arr[-1,:] [298.6107  285.75986]
arr[-2,0] 255.44836

arr [[255.35194 281.08353] # along with this line
 [298.45673 285.88693]]
arr[-1] [298.45673 285.88693]
arr[-2] [255.35194 281.08353]
arr[-2][0] 255.35194
arr[:,0] [255.35194 298.45673]
arr[-1,:] [298.45673 285.88693]
arr[-2,0] 255.35194
```

Other times when I try to index the second to last row it shows me an axis error, which could be the problem(that the appending doesn't add new rows which is what I am trying to index but rather overrides the old values). I don't know. So I tried to switch the appending method with:concatenate, vstack, pandas. But it didn't help.
All I want to do is to find the difference between the last and second to last rows from the second column in the wm element (in the example 280.92575-281.08353) and also the same with the first column of wm element(255.44836-255.35194). All the various indexing methods have not fetched the second to last row just the last row. Please let me know if there's a different way to index the second to last row in a different way or if there are other indexing methods. Sorry if it is confusing still getting used to this. I can try to clear up any confusion. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two displays are the same thing, a `(2,2)` shape array.

```
[[293.51373 323.4329 ]
 [247.77493 316.02783]]

[[293.51373 323.4329 ][247.77493 316.02783]]
```

It's the brackets `[]` that mark the array structure, not the line breaks.

Comment: Interesting, it does make sense but all the normal indexes don't work. And I still don't understand how to index the second to last row, because all the proposed methods just index the last row. As seen in my comment above even [-2::2] indexes the last row. It makes it even more confusing because the array is a 2x2 so I should be able to index the second to last row. First, I thought that it was either I was doing the wrong indexing method or that the appending method is not allowing me to index the second to last row, because in the documentation it says that it doesn't add a new row.

Comment: I've looked at other similar problems, all were resolved by either a new indexing method or a new appending method which I've tried both and in both, I can't fetch the second to last row. Now I am stuck trying new indexing methods hoping one would work. I am open to new indexing or appending methods to see if they produce the necessary results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: With a (2,2) array, the 2nd to the last row is the first row.  There are only 2 rows.  I don't know what you mean by 'the second to last row'.  You seem to have a concept of this array that's quite different from what get from your code.

Comment: Well, if I have one row with wm and hm elements it gets updated with other appended values so the first row I had is now the second-to-last and it continues to update and append new values. I want to index not the latest appended row of values but the one before it.                                          
    second to last row `[[293.51373 323.4329 ][247.77493 316.02783]]` and    
    `[[292.9887  322.23425][247.24142 314.2921 ]]` updated row-so the last one` How to index the 293.51 and 323.43 keeping in mind that it's a separate line of the last one?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is:

```
Arr[-2::2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and contribution but it just indexes the last row of the wm element.   `----arr [[265.75818 269.61978][308.69952 276.45447]]  
arr[-2::2] [[265.75818 269.61978]]   
arr[-1::2] [[308.69952 276.45447]]  
arr[-2::1] [[265.75818 269.61978][308.69952 276.45447]]  
----arr [[265.77682 269.16476]
 [308.67093 275.89474]]  
arr[-2::2] [[265.77682 269.16476]]this line should index 265.75.. and 269.61..
arr[-1::2] [[308.67093 275.89474]]  
arr[-2::1] [[265.77682 269.16476][308.67093 275.89474]]` 
Nevertheless, an interesting way of indexing which I haven't seen before.